# Visual Studio Code - debugging 3 files

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a question about Visual Studio Code Debugging in C++. I have 3 files: main.cpp , functions.hpp , functions.cpp. How to setup up launch.json file for those?

Comment: VSCode is just an IDE, it is not a compiler. You have to [point your configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) to a compiler such as Visual Studio, GCC, or Clang. Here is [an example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) for using Visual Studio.

Comment: You launch and debug your compiled executable with debug information and not your source files.

Comment: Minor nitpick. VSCode is just a text editor that one can transform into an IDE(-ish) if they so desire. If this site can handle a debate about STL vs. C++ Standard Library, I think this one could go down quite easily.